Trimming a video using FFmpeg leads to black screen
I try to figure out how to use FFmpeg to trim videos. I have created a 30 second .mov screen capture using Apple's QuickTime player, and then tried to trim it using three different ways:

Using -copyts, without re-encoding
ffmpeg -copyts -ss 00:00:10 -i input.mov -to 00:00:15 -map 0 -c copy output.mov


Using -copyts, with re-encoding
ffmpeg -copyts -ss 00:00:10 -i input.mov -to 00:00:15 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -b:a 192k output.mov


Using -trim (with re-encoding, which is the only option):
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf trim=10:15 output.mov



No matter which approach I tried, the output video is always 15 seconds long and the first 10 seconds of that is just a black screen, whereas what I expected is a 5-second video and without the black screen.
All the three solutions are from here: https://superuser.com/questions/377343/cut-part-from-video-file-from-start-position-to-end-position-with-ffmpeg (answers by @slhck and @malat), and are very high-voted, so I expect they should work without issues, but they don't. Why is that? Is there a problem with the commands, or with the video?
The video is uploaded here: https://github.com/jsx97/test/blob/main/input.mov

The .mov is generally used with fragmented streaming.
If you stick with quicktime (or) If you output to matroska.
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i input.mov -ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:15 -c copy -movflags +faststart output.mov

ffmpeg -hide_banner -i input.mov -ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:15 -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero output.mkv

Re-encoding:
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i input.mov -ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:15 -c:v libx264 -b:v 809k -c:a aac -b:a 192k -preset ultrafast output.mkv

I had to specify the video bitrate on the re-encode or it throws a big yellow warning.
[out#0/matroska @ 0x5613844e7840] Codec AVOption b (set bitrate (in bits/s)) has not been used for any stream...

Adding -b:v 809k solved it.
All tested working on Fedora 40 with ffmpeg version 6.1.1

Thanks a lot, Jay. Probably I messed everything up in my head, but isn't it that using -crf together with -b:v is superfluous? Isn't it they do the same job, and the main practical difference between them is that -b:v provide a more manual control?

@jsx97 Yes, good call.  That is redundant.  I should have removed it when I added the bitrate.  I usually use constant rate factor over bitrate, which I believe you could still do in this case, because the warning it throws doesn't really affect anything.  But if you don't want to see that error, -b:v is required.  I think the most common reason to use a specified bitrate would be 2-pass encoding.  If your trying to hit an exact file size, variable rate is mandatory.
